# Linux Command Results in a bash Variable

Tags: bash, ping

I am trying to write a Ping result bash code.

this way it work, but i'm not a fan of using the last ouput function:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -q -c2 10.10.50.120 > /dev/null
resp=$?
echo "$resp"
if [ "$resp" == 0 ]
then
    echo "ok"
else
  echo "not ok"
fi
```

Ouput:

```
0
ok
```

but this way it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

resp=$(ping -q -c2 10.10.50.120 > /dev/null)
echo "$resp"
if [ "$resp" == 0 ]
then
    echo "ok"
else
  echo "not ok"
fi
```

Ouput:

```
not ok
```

Can anyone help me to find out how to write it correctly?

Comment: What is the wrong of your first script?

Comment: The first test is testing the exit status of `ping` the second is testing if the (output)  value of the `ping` command is equals to zero. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response! The firsr scrpit work fine, but I wanted to avoid the "$?" function. It is possible to save the exit status to a variable without the "$?" function?

Comment: @DavidStegmüller: Please make up your mind: Do you really want to know the _exit_ status, or do you want to know whether the exit status _is zero_. In the first case, the only place where the exit status is stored, is the variable $?. In the latter case, there are several program construct which lets you do conditional execution based on the zero-ness of the exit status of a command.

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted to avoid the "$?" function.

That's great. So just use `if`.

```
if output=$(ping -q -c2 10.10.50.120); then
# or like: if ping -q -c2 10.10.50.120 >/dev/null; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
echo "Anyway, ping command ouptutted: $output"
```

> It is possible to save the exit status to a variable without the "$?" function?

No.